# Finding the smallest number whose sum of the digits is equal to a given N

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

I am solving a question on [Geeks For Geeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-smallest-number-whose-sum-of-digits-is-n/). The problem is to find the smallest number whose sum is equal to the given N. The solution is being determined by the formula [Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3nIr.png) But I don't understand how are we reaching at this formula?

Comment: Your formula link is broken.  But...Isn't the answer always $x999\cdots 9$?  Here, $x$ would just be the remainder on dividing $N$ by $9$.  Or am I mistaken?

Comment: Yes you're correct

Comment: Can you please tell me how did you find this?

Comment: It's obvious.  Consider the minimal solution.  Suppose that there was some digit, other than the lead digit, that was less than $9$...then you could subtract one from the lead digit and add it to that digit and get a smaller solution, contradicting minimality.  Thus, for example, $68$ sums to $14$ but it's better to take one from the $6$ and add it to the $8$ to get $59$ which is the true solution.

Comment: Sorry but Not quite getting your point.

Comment: Well, think about it. What part of my argument do you find confusing?

Comment: Okay, do you mean to say like this:-   suppose we're having the number as 84 then we subtract from 8 and add to the units place and we keep on doing this until we find 9 at the unit place?

Comment: That's what I said, only of course it doesn't have to be the units place.  If you started with $3899$ you would replace it with $2999$, for instance.

Comment: I suppose one should remark that there always is a solution, though that's clear, yes?  My form always gives a solution or you could just take $N$ $1's$.  Once you have some solution, it's clear that there is a unique minimum.

Comment: Okay i get this but how does the formula fit into this scenario?  Like how are we even achieving this formula??

Comment: I have given you an explicit solution!  I really don't understand what else there is to say.  Take $N$.  Write it as $N=r+9q$ where $0≤r<9$.  Then the smallest number with digit sum $N$ is $r\underbrace{9\cdots 9}_{q\;\text {times}}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula given on the site is

$$(N \bmod 9 + 1)\cdot 10^{\left\lfloor \dfrac{N}{9}\right\rfloor}- 1$$

Meaning that whatever the number $N$, we want to stick as many $9$s as possible in the number (to reach $N$ faster). For that we simply divide $N$ by $9$, which gives the number of $9$s to use, and the final digit is the remainder of that $\dfrac{N}{9}$, or $N \bmod 9$.

We could put that final remainder digit anywhere, like $99399$, but since the smallest number is requested, that digit will be leading the number (like $39999$).

For $N=31$, we have $N=31=3\cdot 9+4$, so we know  we need three $9$, and the remainder, $4$. The number would be $4999$.

The formula above does the same thing in one single calculation. Instead of building the number by piling the $9s$, it finds the resulting number $+1$, that is a power of $10$ multiplied by a digit, and then subtract $1$ to reach the solution. For $N=31$, that would be $5000-1$.

- the $(N \bmod 9+1)$ finds the remainder, and adds one to it ($5$ in the example)
- the $10^{\left\lfloor \dfrac{N}{9} \right\rfloor}$ gives the number of $0s$ to (powers of $10$) to give to that number, $\left\lfloor \dfrac{N}{9} \right\rfloor$ gives the integer part of $N/9$. ($3$ in the example)
- finally subtract $1$ ($5000-1$ in the example)

Comment: Thank You! Got it